# Django: models, views and templates

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to do a very simple thing in Django but getting stuck since I'm a newbie. Basically, on a doctor page in my website, I'm trying to add a field where a user can enter the waiting time for that doctor. For this, I wrote the following model in my models.py:

```
class WaitingTime(models.Model):
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    time = models.IntegerField("Waiting Time", max_length=2)
```

After this I wrote the following view:

```
def WaitingTime(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = WaitingTime(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            doctor = form.cleaned_data['doctor']
            user = form.cleaned_data['user']
            time = form.cleaned_data['time']
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') 
    else:
        form = WaitingTime()
```

This view is the part that I'm most unsure about. Even though I've done 2 tutorials, I feel like a total noob when I have to write this view.

And then, I added this code to my template:

```
<h4>Please enter the waiting time that you experienced for this doctor.</h4>
<form action="/WaitingTime/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="hidden" name="doctor" value="{{ doctor.name }}" />
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="{{ user.username }}" />
WaitingTime: <input type="text" name="time"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

So basically, I'm having trouble adding data from the front end to my database, something very trivial and basic. I already ran python manage.py syncdb and checked using the SQLite Database Browser. The table with the appropriate columns has been added. Please help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In order to make changes to the database your views needs to be changed to -

```
def WaitingTime(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = WaitingTimeForm(request.POST) #class specified in forms.py
        if form.is_valid():
            doctor = form.cleaned_data['doctor']
            user = form.cleaned_data['user']
            time = form.cleaned_data['time']
            WaitingTimeObject = WaitingTime(doctor=doctor, user=user, time=time)
            WaitingTimeObject.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made the change. However, when I try to submit the form data, I get an error that says "AttributeError at /WaitingTime/
'WaitingTime' object has no attribute 'get'"

Comment: That is because your model and form names are the same. I would change the form class to `WaitingTimeForm()` Also, the view name is the same - conflict again !!

Comment: I think @karthir may have solved your doubt.
Did you create a forms.py file? In forms.py, make sure the class is WaitingTimeForm (check the edit I made to the answer).

Comment: Check the following doc link - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#form-objects